# SpriteKit huge performance drop when purging SKTextureAtlas

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, texture-atlas, sktextureatlas

I have a very strange problem when purging a cached instance of `SKTextureAtlas`.

In short, before the game starts I preload the `SKTextureAtlas` with `textureAtlas.preload(completionHandler:)` and in the completion handler I store a reference to the atlas in a private property, in order to keep it in the memory for the later use.

After a while, this texture atlas is not needed anymore and I want to get rid of it, in order to maintain a clean and healthy memory.

**Problem**

The problem I'm having is that when I purge the texture atlas (by setting the property which was holding a reference to the atlas to `nil`), the performance drops drastically for a few seconds. By drastically, I mean from a constant 60fps to 40fps.

*Note that there is **definitely** no other reference to that atlas left at this point.*

---

**Interesting: part 1**

Only happens on iOS 10. Runs perfectly on iOS 9, even on much older device.

**Interesting: part 2**

Happens only if the atlas is defined in form of `.spriteatlas` inside the `.xcassets`. but not if the atlas is an `.atlas` folder outside of the `.xcassets`.

*I know I could just go ahead and use `.atlas` instead of `.spriteatlas`, but `.spriteatlas` support app-thinning out of the box, which `.atlas` doesn't.*

**Interesting: part 3**

Purging works fine if the atlas has a small number of small textures. This indicates that there might be an internal issue related the total size of the atlas. But why?

**Motivation**

The motivation behind finding a solution/workaround to this problem is *batching of bind/draw calls*. Child nodes that use the same texture are all rendered in a single draw pass, which of course increases performance a lot.

With this problem, I'm basically forced to create multiple atlases which will in turn result in having multiple draw calls and therefore affect the overall performance.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update**

I've tried implementing a solution suggested by @Knight0fDragon, which suggest caching `SKTexture`s from `SKTextureAtlas` instead of `SKTextureAtlas` itself, but that sadly didn't work in my case.

What I forgot to mention in the original question is that this problem happens most of the times, but not always. I get it to work perfectly fine every ~5th try.

---

**Solution**

Since I wasn't able to re-open my question after being wrongly marked as duplicate, I'll just post the solution I found here.

The problem was an animation running in the background. This animation was set up like this

```
let rotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
rotation.fromValue = 0
rotation.toValue = 2 * M_PI
rotation.duration = 110
rotation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
```

and it was running on the layer of `UIImageView`. This image view was located in the view controller that eventually presented another view controller which contains a game scene.

The transition between those two view controllers is custom, and since I forgot to add calls to `beginAppearanceTransition` and `endAppearanceTransition` in the custom transition animator, the view controller lifecycle methods (`viewWillAppear:`, `viewWillDisappear`) were not called, which is exactly where I had the logic for starting/stopping all animations. Therefore the animation kept on running in the background.

That said, even if the animation was running in the background, it should not interfere with something completely unrelated like clearing the cached atlas.

*Note: the image in the image view with problematic animation was **not** defined in the problematic texture atlas.*

Comment: issue is because it is constantly making new textures now

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I see. :/ After reading the thread in your question I wasn't able to see any solutions. Did you find a way to overcome this?

Comment: yes,  I had to make a dictionary that stored all the textures from the atlas, so that it only created it once

Comment: I will make an answer now for you

Comment: @Knight0fDragon awesome! Thank you. :+1:

Comment: I posted it on my question

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks!

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'm voting for this question to be re-opened since your solution hasn't worked in my case. Seems like there is some other issue somewhere. :| What I forgot to add in the question is that it happens most of the time, but not always, which is even more strange.

Comment: I would need to see it in action then

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'm trying to create an empty sample project to show it to you but now SpriteKit won't show real fps for some reason. It just constantly shows `1.0 fps` in a clean, empty project. On a real device. Oh my.

Comment: maybe it is your setup then lol

Comment: @Knight0fDragon What setup? :) It's a clean project without any modifications whatsoever.

Comment: i mean your OS X or Xcode yada yada

Comment: @Knight0fDragon see the solution above.

Comment: Yeah that is why I needed to see the project,  your issue had nothing to do with atlases